# How can I use R-scripts containing Umlauts cross-platform?

Tags: r, rstudio, diacritics

I'm using Windows on my Desktop PC at work and Linux on my Laptop. I frequently work on R-scripts in Rstudio alternating between the two machines. Whenever I try to import scripts that contain umlauts on one system after working with the other, the umlauts (e.g. ä,ü,ß,ö) are replaced with question marks. Importantly, I'm not talking about data that I am importing but the text in the script itself. For example, writing the following script file in Linux:

```
# This iß an exämple
text <- c("R kann äußerst nervig sein")
```

Will be displayed differently when opened on Windows:

```
# This i? an ex?mple
text <- c("R kann ?u?erst nervig sein")
```

Are there any settings that prevent this from happening? I've already tried to set the standard encoding to utf-8 on both machines but it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Your terminal has to also be utf-8

Comment: @Mossa Would this do the trick? ```Sys.setenv(LANG = "de_DE.UTF-8")```

Comment: No idea, I just googled a little bit and found this. I've a bit of experience with this, but not the shiny part. Next place to look at is the "shiny" manifest. Again, don't know what that is.

Comment: ```Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","German")```

Comment: We're talking about saving and opening text files in the editor part of RStudio here - I don't understand how that would be affected by how the R locale is set up. @JuKo: when you write you "set the standard encoding to utf-8", do you mean your operating system or RStudio?

Answer (score 2):

The standard R build on Windows doesn't fully support UTF-8, because Windows itself just added that capability very recently.  So you could download the "WinUCRT" build of R (though I forget the location, Google probably knows), and then things would be fine.

Alternatively, for widest portability you could write your scripts in pure ascii by encoding the accented letters as Unicode escapes.  The `stringi` package can help with this, e.g.

```r
cat(stringi::stri_escape_unicode("R kann äußerst nervig sein"))
#> R kann \u00e4u\u00dferst nervig sein
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

so you'd put this in your code:

```
text <- "R kann \u00e4u\u00dferst nervig sein"
```

(There's no need to call `c()` for one element.)  This is inconvenient, but should work on all systems.

Comment: Thanks! The "WinUCRT" version looks interesting, I'll have a look at that!